# UnicodeDecodeError when trying to encode/decode CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, base64, encode

I am trying to figure out how to make the following function work. Basically, what I'm trying to achieve with this function is to create a csv file from a DataFrame, encode it, and then decode it for download.:

```
def filedownload(df):
  csv = df.to_csv(index=False, encoding='utf-8')
  # strings <-> bytes conversion
  encoded = base64.b64encode(csv)
  decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
  href = f'<a href="data:file/csv;base64,{decoded}" download="prediction.csv">Download Predictions</a>'
  return href
```

However, when running the entire program, I get the following error:

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 354, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/app/bioactivity_app.py", line 97, in <module>
    build_model(desc_subset)
File "/app/bioactivity_app.py", line 35, in build_model
    load_model = pickle.load(open('sars_cov_proteinase_model.pkl'))
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

This is an example of what the input CSV file looks like: https://ufile.io/sbl163ty
This is part of the code I'm using to generate this file:

```
prediction_output = pd.Series(Y_pred, name = 'pIC50')
molecule_name = pd.Series(load_data['molecular_id'], name = 'Molecule Name')
df2 = pd.concat([molecule_name, prediction_output], axis=1)
csv = df2.to_csv('example_generated.csv')
```

I believe it has something to do with how the file is getting encoded but am not sure. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What does your csv look like? Can you upload it somewhere and send a link?

Comment: You should really include the entire error trace here, not just the last line.  It's not enough information.

Comment: Just updated my post! @user17242583

Comment: You really have no reason to encode a csv file in base64. Despite Microsoft claiming that it is an Excel format, a CSV file is a portable **text** file. You should be able to dowload and upload it with no further conversion.

Comment: Ok so from reading through the error trace again and getting rid of the base64 process, I realized the error wasn't in the encoding of the CSV but another file I'm using for the app, which was a pretty easy fix. Thank you all!